# mapreduce - Couldn't find MR with job ID

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am running Java mapreduce.  I get the following exception
/admin/mapreduce/mapperCallback
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find MR with job ID:

Params in the mapreduce.xml
mapreduce.mapper.inputprocessingrate = 100
mapreduce.mapper.shardcount = 1

It has been asked in the past here about this exception, but there was no proper replies.

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved with help from Mike.  I am using namespaces with in the map(), and I was not resetting to empty namespace at the end of the call.